# Querying Eloquent hasMany returning columnize error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm attempting to query a model I setup in laravel.  All I want to do is get all the `categories` in my `categories` table that have the given `App\Category` instance as their `parent`.  Unfortanutely, my hasMany is returning `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given, called in /Users/infosec/kannopy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 122`

Here's my `App\Category` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'name'];

    /**
    * return the items in a category
    */
    public function items(){
      $this->hasMany('App\Item', 'category_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
    * return the categories parent category
    */
    public function parent_category(){
      $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent', 'id');
    }

    /**
    * get a list of the child categories of any given category
    */
    public function children(){
      $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent', 'id');
    }


}
```

Here's the controller where I'm doing the query:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Category;
class CategoryController extends Controller
{

    /**
    * return the children of a given category
    */
    public function getChildren($id){
        $parent =  Category::find($id);
        return $parent->children();
    }
}
```

Additionally, here's the database migration for the `category` table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('parent')->unsigned()->nullable(); //this needs to be done before the foreign key constraint
            $table->foreign('parent')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

Finally, here's the full traceback (as a html sinppet):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
        <style>
            /* Copyright (c) 2010, Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved. Code licensed under the BSD License: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/license.html */
            html{color:#000;background:#FFF;}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:text-top;}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}legend{color:#000;}

            html { background: #eee; padding: 10px }
            img { border: 0; }
            #sf-resetcontent { width:970px; margin:0 auto; }
                        .sf-reset { font: 11px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; color: #333 }
            .sf-reset .clear { clear:both; height:0; font-size:0; line-height:0; }
            .sf-reset .clear_fix:after { display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; }
            .sf-reset .clear_fix { display:inline-block; }
            .sf-reset * html .clear_fix { height:1%; }
            .sf-reset .clear_fix { display:block; }
            .sf-reset, .sf-reset .block { margin: auto }
            .sf-reset abbr { border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; cursor: help; }
            .sf-reset p { font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#868686; padding-bottom:20px }
            .sf-reset strong { font-weight:bold; }
            .sf-reset a { color:#6c6159; cursor: default; }
            .sf-reset a img { border:none; }
            .sf-reset a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
            .sf-reset em { font-style:italic; }
            .sf-reset h1, .sf-reset h2 { font: 20px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif }
            .sf-reset .exception_counter { background-color: #fff; color: #333; padding: 6px; float: left; margin-right: 10px; float: left; display: block; }
            .sf-reset .exception_title { margin-left: 3em; margin-bottom: 0.7em; display: block; }
            .sf-reset .exception_message { margin-left: 3em; display: block; }
            .sf-reset .traces li { font-size:12px; padding: 2px 4px; list-style-type:decimal; margin-left:20px; }
            .sf-reset .block { background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:10px 28px; margin-bottom:20px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 16px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 16px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
                border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
                border-right:1px solid #ccc;
                border-left:1px solid #ccc;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            .sf-reset .block_exception { background-color:#ddd; color: #333; padding:20px;
                -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 16px;
                -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 16px;
                -moz-border-radius-topleft: 16px;
                -moz-border-radius-topright: 16px;
                border-top-left-radius: 16px;
                border-top-right-radius: 16px;
                border-top:1px solid #ccc;
                border-right:1px solid #ccc;
                border-left:1px solid #ccc;
                overflow: hidden;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            .sf-reset a { background:none; color:#868686; text-decoration:none; }
            .sf-reset a:hover { background:none; color:#313131; text-decoration:underline; }
            .sf-reset ol { padding: 10px 0; }
            .sf-reset h1 { background-color:#FFFFFF; padding: 15px 28px; margin-bottom: 20px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
                -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
                    <div id="sf-resetcontent" class="sf-reset">
                <h1>Whoops, looks like something went wrong.</h1>
                                        <h2 class="block_exception clear_fix">
                            <span class="exception_counter">1/1</span>
                            <span class="exception_title"><abbr title="Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError">FatalThrowableError</abbr> in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php line 107" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Grammar.php line 107</a>:</span>
                            <span class="exception_message">Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given, called in /Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 122</span>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="block">
                            <ol class="traces list_exception">
       <li> in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php line 107" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Grammar.php line 107</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Grammar">Grammar</abbr>->columnize('1') in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php line 122" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Grammar.php line 122</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar">Grammar</abbr>->compileColumns(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder">Builder</abbr>), '1') in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php line 76" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Grammar.php line 76</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar">Grammar</abbr>->compileComponents(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder">Builder</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php line 52" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Grammar.php line 52</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar">Grammar</abbr>->compileSelect(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder">Builder</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php line 38" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">MySqlGrammar.php line 38</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\MySqlGrammar">MySqlGrammar</abbr>->compileSelect(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder">Builder</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php line 1578" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Builder.php line 1578</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder">Builder</abbr>->toSql() in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php line 1645" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Builder.php line 1645</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder">Builder</abbr>->runSelect() in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php line 1631" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Builder.php line 1631</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder">Builder</abbr>->get('1') in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php line 613" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Builder.php line 613</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder">Builder</abbr>->getModels('1') in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php line 318" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Builder.php line 318</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder">Builder</abbr>->get('1') in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php line 288" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Builder.php line 288</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder">Builder</abbr>->first('1') in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php line 168" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Builder.php line 168</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder">Builder</abbr>->find('id', '1')</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array(<em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder">Builder</abbr>), 'find'), <em>array</em>('id', '1')) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php line 3516" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Model.php line 3516</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model">Model</abbr>->__call('find', <em>array</em>('id', '1'))</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array(<em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="App\Category">Category</abbr>), 'find'), <em>array</em>('id', '1')) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php line 3530" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Model.php line 3530</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model">Model</abbr>::__callStatic('find', <em>array</em>('id', '1')) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/app/Http/Controllers/CategoryController.php line 17" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">CategoryController.php line 17</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController">CategoryController</abbr>->getChildren('1')</li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>call_user_func_array(<em>array</em>(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController">CategoryController</abbr>), 'getChildren'), <em>array</em>('id' => '1')) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php line 55" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Controller.php line 55</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Controller">Controller</abbr>->callAction('getChildren', <em>array</em>('id' => '1')) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php line 44" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">ControllerDispatcher.php line 44</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher">ControllerDispatcher</abbr>->dispatch(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController">CategoryController</abbr>), 'getChildren') in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php line 189" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Route.php line 189</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>->runController() in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php line 144" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Route.php line 144</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>->run(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php line 642" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Router.php line 642</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Router">Router</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 53" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 53</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php line 41" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">SubstituteBindings.php line 41</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings">SubstituteBindings</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 137" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 137</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 33" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 33</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php line 48" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">ThrottleRequests.php line 48</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests">ThrottleRequests</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>), '60', '1') in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 137" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 137</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 33" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 33</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 104" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 104</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->then(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php line 644" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Router.php line 644</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Router">Router</abbr>->runRouteWithinStack(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Route">Route</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php line 618" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Router.php line 618</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Router">Router</abbr>->dispatchToRoute(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php line 596" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Router.php line 596</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Router">Router</abbr>->dispatch(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php line 267" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Kernel.php line 267</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel">Kernel</abbr>->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 53" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 53</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/Debugbar.php line 51" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Debugbar.php line 51</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\Debugbar">Debugbar</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 137" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 137</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 33" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 33</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode">CheckForMaintenanceMode</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>), <em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 137" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 137</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php line 33" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 33</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php line 104" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Pipeline.php line 104</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline">Pipeline</abbr>->then(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Closure">Closure</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php line 149" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Kernel.php line 149</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel">Kernel</abbr>->sendRequestThroughRouter(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php line 116" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Kernel.php line 116</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title="Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel">Kernel</abbr>->handle(<em>object</em>(<abbr title="Illuminate\Http\Request">Request</abbr>)) in <a title="/Users/infosec/myProject/public/index.php line 53" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">index.php line 53</a></li>
       <li>at <abbr title=""></abbr>require('/Users/infosec/myProject/public/index.php') in <a title="/Users/infosec/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php line 106" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">server.php line 106</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `parents` function should not be in `Category` class but in `Item` class

Category class

```
public function parent_category(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent', 'id');
}

public function children(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent', 'id');
}
```

And your controller's function should be as:

```
public function getChildren($id){
    $parent =  Category::where('id', $id)->with('children')->first();
    return $parent->children;
}
```

or

```
public function getChildren($id){
    return Category::where('parent', $id)->get();
}
```

The first code runs two query to find the parent then finds it's children whereas the second one runs single query and directly finds the children by the id of parent.

Comment: If you look at my migration, the parent foreign key constraint references the categories table.  I do want the parent to be a parent on the categories table

Comment: Oh okay, I see where you went wrong.  That comment should say category, not item.  Let me fix that in the OP

Comment: But still, the relation was wrong. In `belongsTo` the FK should be `parent` not `category_id`. As there is no `category_id` column in category table.

Comment: And one more thing your relation function should not be named as `parent` as there is already a column named parent in category table. They will conflict with each other. You can change it like `parent_category`.

Comment: Okay, both of those are fixed.  So when I try your first solution `$parent =  Category::where('id', $id)->with('children')->first();` I get `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null`.  This is not because the result is null, as when I do return  `Category::where('id', $id)->first();` I get a result, so I don't know why that is.

As for your second solution: `return Category::where('parent', $id)->get();` I know that will work, but in that case there's no point to using eloquent at all.  The goal with the children() function was to separate the db logic from the controller.

Comment: The problem was the missing `return` statements in the `children` relation method. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Wow!  I don't know how I missed that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's really unclear what you are trying to do here

```
public function getChildren($id){
    $parent =  Category::find('id', $id)->children();
    return $parent->children();
}
```

Try replacing it with this

```
public function getChildren($id){
    $parent =  Category::find($id);
    return $parent->children;
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  So the first line is working now `    $parent =  Category::find($id);` but on children I'm getting: Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation